# get_row returns empty when data exists

Tags: wpdb, plugin-contact-form-7, get-row

I am trying to run the following query to access my WP cf7dbplugin_submits table but it keeps coming up empty. I have added my table into wp-db.php model as such:

```
Added the contact form table- cf7dbplugin_submits to the following at about line 268:
    var $tables = array('cf7dbplugin_submits','posts', . . .)

At around line 304 add the following:
    /**
     * WordPress cf7dbplugin_submits table
     */
    public $cf7dbplugin_submits;
```

So the database function should find it (it has when used elsewhere in my code).  But the following is consistently coming up empty for any $postid:

```
function action_getpost($postid) {
  global $wpdb, $out;
  $out['post'] = array();
  $out['uploads'] = array();

    // wp_posts has one row for each submitted form.
    // wp_nf_objectmeta includes a set of rows for each defined form.

    $query =
    "SELECT submit_time, form_name, field_value" .
    "FROM $wpdb->cf7dbplugin_submits " .
    "WHERE field_order = %d AND submit_time = %d ";

    $queryp = $wpdb->prepare($query, array(9999, $postid));
    if (empty($queryp)) {
      $out['errmsg'] = "Internal error: \"$query\" \"$postid\"";
      return;
    }
    $wpdb->show_errors( true );
    $row = $wpdb->get_row($queryp, ARRAY_A);
    if (empty($row)) {
      $out['errmsg'] = "No rows matching: \"$postid\"";
      return;
    }
```

If I just run the following query in phpMyAdmin, where $postid = 1445125066.4375:

```
SELECT submit_time, form_name, field_value
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE field_order = 9999 AND submit_time = 1445125066.4375
```

It produces the needed row

```
submit_time         form_name       field_value
1445125066.4375     Demographics    usernamehere
```

So why is the function returning my error of no rows matching 1445125066.4375?  Any ideas?

Comment: If `$postid` is supposed to be a WordPress post ID it isn't ever going to be a decimal.

Comment: Thanks, there is no key in the wp_cf7dbplugin_submits table.  The closest thing I have to identify posts there is the unix timestamp with milliseconds in 'submit_time'.  This with the field order of 9999 will get me the distinct form data I need. The timestamp is what I am using for $postid and it should match 'submit_time'.  So, will it not be possible to use this?

Comment: Weird variable name, but where is `$postid` set?

Comment: Yes, what I am doing is trying to rework existing open source code that was developed for Ninja Forms integration to work with Contactform 7 instead. In the Ninja Forms version $postid was set to wp_post.ID.  Where is it set?: First the user sees all form submissions for a form_name (e.g. Demographics). This part works fine.  On clicking submission, $postid in this case is set to submit_time for that submission and the function action_getpost is called with the $postid. My CF7 query yields the same data as the Ninja query did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it was an issue of the decimal point which was pointed by s_ha_dum.  But for different reasons.  The place holder %d is integer.  I need %f for floating point.  Now it works.  And thanks to s_ha_dum I have more parsimonious code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things going on there and I may not be able to sort them all out.

1. Unless `$wpdb->cf7dbplugin_submits` has been added to the `$wpdb`
   object your query won't work. You will need something like
   `{$wpdb->prefix}cf7dbplugin_submits` instead but I can't really
   guess at the right value.
2. You don't need to swap in 9999. That is a hard-code value. Swapping
   it in with `prepare` is a waste of resources.
3. Prepare accepts 3 different placeholders, one for a string, one for
   a digit, and one for float. By using `%d` you are truncating your
   decimal. You need `%f`.

Perhaps something like this will work better:

```
$query =
"SELECT submit_time, form_name, field_value" .
"FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cf7dbplugin_submits " .
"WHERE field_order = 9999 AND submit_time = %f ";

$queryp = $wpdb->prepare($query, $postid);
```

Item #2 won't cause a failure of the query, but item #1 would, so that is where I am betting this goes wrong. However, item #3 would just as likely break the query as you would not get a match on a decimal value if the decimal input was truncated to an integer.

Comment: Thanks.  I made adjustments with 9999. cf7dbplugin_submits was added to $wpdb so that is not an issue.  I tried just writing 1445125066.4375 into the query. It passed to get_row with no error. The next part of the code works. So for some reason prepare is not passing $postid to %d in the query. But $postid is being passed to the error code.  So, I know I am accessing the table.  And I know that $postid is set before reaching the function.  prepare is not filling %d.  I am not sure why.

Comment: @CraigTucker : Ha! Got it. Give me two minutes and check the edit.